# Discord.py How can take a variable from one class and use it in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, discord.py

In short, I am trying to do a "are you sure" kind of verification system whenever a user makes a specific input to make sure they are confident in their decision.

My initial thought was to call the variable InputPronouns from the pronoun method inside the pronounCmd class to my button class, named PronounsView.

I've tried a couple things like assigning the class to a variable P inside PronounsView and trying to call the InputPronouns variable from that... but that didn't work.

```
class pronounCmd(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.client = bot
# please error handle for when user types in a number #
    @app_commands.command(name = "pronoun", description = "Give yourself a custom role based on pronouns of your choosing.")
    async def pronoun(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, pronoun_1: str, pronoun_2: str):
        self.InputPronouns = f'{pronoun_1}/{pronoun_2}'
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "You have chosen the following pronouns to give yourself!", description = "", color = 0x32a852)
        embed.add_field(name = f'{self.InputPronouns}', value = "", inline = False)
        embed.add_field(name = "Are you sure you want these pronouns as your role? You can always change it later.", value = "", inline = False)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view = PronounsView())

# Buttons to act as verification for whether IS SURE about they pronouns they are choosing
class PronounsView(discord.ui.View):
    # Yes Button
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Yes", style = discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def YesButton(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        P = pronounCmd()
        p_role = P.InputPronouns
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'{p_role}')
```

I've tried a couple things like assigning the class to a variable P inside PronounsView and trying to call the InputPronouns variable from that... but that didn't work. My expectation was that when I click the Yes button inside my guild it would spew my inputs back at me which does not happen. I think it's worth mentioning I also got this error when I click the button

```
[2023-02-06 00:16:54] [ERROR   ] discord.ui.view: Ignoring exception in view <PronounsView timeout=180.0 children=2> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Yes' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prodk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "d:\Coding Stuff\discord bots\Gender Reaction Role Bot\cogs\pronoun.py", line 24, in YesButton
    P = pronounCmd()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: pronounCmd.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bot'
```

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. What exactly is unclear about the error message? We don't offer "help" here, because this is **not a discussion forum** and that is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/). "My initial thought was to ... but that didn't work" - rather than explaining what you are writing, please focus on thinking about what *problem you are trying to solve* and *specifically what is going wrong* with that.

Comment: For example: where the code says `P = pronounCmd()`, what do you think this will do - will it use the existing `pronounCmd`, or will it create a new one? Which of those things *should* happen? (Hint: would a new `pronounCmd` created from scratch, have the `InputPronouns` information set up already? How?)

Comment: "How can take a variable from one class and use it in another class?" - the reason you are having difficulty solving the problem is that, when you are thinking about the problem, you are using the words inaccurately. What you are trying to do is use an *attribute* of an *instance of* the class. It is vital to distinguish classes from their instances. You can live inside a house. You cannot live inside the abstract concept of houses.